# UTF-8 (in literal) to hebrew

Tags: encoding, utf-8, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, hebrew

i'm trying to web scrape a site that has hebrew in it using BeautifulSoup python. the html comes out fine but the content in the tags comes out like so:

```
<span class="color_11">\xc2\xa0\xd7\x91\xd7\x97\xd7\xa9\xd7\x91\xd7\x95\xd7\xa0\xd7\x95\xd7\xaa \xd7\x9c\xd7\xa7\xd7\x95\xd7\x97 \xd7\x92\xd7\x93\xd7\x95\xd7\x9c\xd7\x99\xd7\x9d I\xc2\xa0\xd7\xa4\xd7\x99\xd7\xaa\xd7\x95\xd7\x97 \xd7\x9e\xd7\x9b\xd7\x99\xd7\xa8\xd7\x95\xd7\xaa \xc2\xa0\xd7\x90\xd7\x99\xd7\xa9\xd7\x99 \xd7\x95\xd7\xa7\xd7\x91\xd7\x95\xd7\xa6\xd7\xaa\xd7\x99 \xd7\x91\xd7\x9e\xd7\x92\xd7\xa8\xd7\xa9 \xd7\x94\xd7\x91\xd7\x99\xd7\xa6\xd7\x95\xd7\xa2\xd7\x99\xd7\x9d</span>
```

according to this table i found: https://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1408&number=128&utf8=string-literal

this is UTF-8 (in literal). how do i turn it into it's coresponding hebrew character?

added the code i ran:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen

my_url = "Website_url"

uclient = urlopen(my_url)
page_html = uclient.read()
uclient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")

with open("source.txt","w") as file:
    a = str(page_soup.p.encode())
    file.write(a)
```

Comment: Is that part of a Javascript literal…? That's not valid/useful HTML.

Comment: i'm writing the output into a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
a = str(page_soup.p.encode())
```

with

```
a = str(page_soup.p)
```

With this change, your code (pointed at he.wikipedia.org) does the right thing.

Comment: i receive this error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 29457-29458: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Strange. As I said, I tested that (on Mac though, Windows might do something stupid instead). Did you see if your code with my change works correctly for you for the Wikipedia link I tested on? That should see if the problem is in the page or in code/environment... Does it change anything if you do force the encoding, `open("source.txt","w", encoding="utf-8")`?

Comment: Yes! adding open("source.txt","w", encoding="utf-8") solved it. thanks!